# How to stop swiping at last slide?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I feel bad that I have to ask for help in this forum but the site I downloaded the script from does not have any form of help.

Anyway, I'm using a swiping script from [iDangerous Swiper](http://www.idangero.us/sliders/swiper/). I can't figure out how to stop the swiping at the last slide or div. Anyway suggestion is much appreciated. I'm using the [default](http://www.idangero.us/sliders/swiper/demos.php) swipe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the [API options section](http://www.idangero.us/sliders/swiper/api.php), it says that the default for looping is false...but have you tried explicitly setting it to false?

```
var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', { 
    speed:750,
    loop: false
})
```

It looks like in their "default" example they are setting loop to true:

```
var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container',{
    pagination: '.pagination',
    loop: true,
    grabCursor: true,
    paginationClickable: true
})
```

If you simply remove, the loop property it may fix your issue.

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](http://www.idangero.us/sliders/swiper/api.php) for **iDangerous Swiper**, it looks like you should add the `noSwipingClass` css class to the `div` for the **last slide**.

Via: http://www.idangero.us/sliders/swiper/api.php

```
noSwipingClass  
string  
'swiper-no-swiping' 
'stop-swiping'   
CSS class of html element that will be used to prevent swiping when "noSwiping" parameter is set to true.
```